# Completely separated sets in a Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a Tychonoff space and $f_1,f_2$ are two real-valued continuous functions on $X$. If $A$ and $B$ are two completely separated sets in $X$, Can we find a $g\in C(X)$ such that $g(x)=f_1(x)$ for all $x\in A$ and $g(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x\in B$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ and $B$ are completely separated, there exists a continuous function $p$ such that $p(x)=1$ on $A$, and $p(x)=0$ on $B$.

Let, $g(x)=p(x)f_1(x)+(1-p(x))f_2(x)$, then, for all $x\in A$, $g(x)=f_1(x)$, and $g(x)=f_2(x)$ on $B$.

Functions $f_1$, $f_2$ and $p$ are continuous, hence $g \in C(X)$.

Therefore, such function $g$ exists.

Comment: @ana you are welcome!

Comment: take $g(x)=p(x)f_1(x)+(1-p(x))f_2(x)$

Comment: @ana edited! for two functions.